# Azure REST API: Stop a classic service

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services, azure-rest-api, azure-management-api, azure-management

I'm trying to invoke Azure REST API from Powershell to start/stop a classic service.

```
$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer $($token.Token)")
$headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json") 
$response = Invoke-RestMethod "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/$subscriptionId/resourceGroups/$rscGrp/providers/Microsoft.ClassicCompute/domainNames/$serviceName/slots/production/$action?api-version=2020-02-01" -Method 'POST' -Headers $headers
$response | ConvertTo-Json
```

When `$action="start"`, the command works perfectly and the service starts all instances as required.
However, when `$action="stop"`, the command deletes the whole service all together. The whole deployment slot is deleted instead of simply stopping the instances.
Basically, I want it to behave exactly like clicking on the "stop" button in Azure Portal.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/cloud-services/power-off), to Power off the cloud service. Note that resources are still attached and you are getting charged for the resources

```
POST https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Compute/cloudServices/{cloudServiceName}/poweroff?api-version=2021-03-01
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're referencing a classic cloud service. I'm not sure how it translates to the management.azure.com endpoint, but on the old https://management.core.windows.net endpoint, I believe you're looking for [Update Deployment Status](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/reference/ee460808(v=azure.100)) with a desire to set the status to "Suspended".

The behavior is the same as the other answer specified for the Microsoft.Compute/cloudServices response: the roles will stop, but you will still be charged for them.